# In AppEngine (JDO), what is the difference between equality (==) of an item with list and contains() function?

Tags: google-app-engine, list, performance, jdo

For example, if I have: `List A;` and a `String B;`

What is the difference, in JDO (AppEngine), between the following two conditions in a query: `B == A;` and `A.contains(B);`?

Also, does the query in Slides 23-25 of http://dl.google.com/io/2009/pres/W_0415_Building_Scalable_Complex_App_Engines.pdf work efficiently in AppEngine (JDO) for more than 30 receivers? How so, especially since I read in AppEngine documentation that each contains() query can have a maximum of 30 items in the list. Do I not use a contains() query to imitate the above slides (written in Python)? If not, then how can I achieve the same results in JDO?

Any suggestions/comments are highly welcome. I'm trying to build a messaging system in AppEngine but having trouble trying to get used to the platform.

Thanks.

Comment: "A == B" is invalid JDOQL, as Google know. It should not be used, for portability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no difference - in App Engine, equality checks on lists are the same as checking for containment, due to the way things are indexed in the datastore.

By the query on slides 23-25, I presume you mean this one?

```
indexes = db.GqlQuery(
    "SELECT __key__ FROM MessageIndex "
    "WHERE receivers = :1", me)
keys = [k.parent() for k in indexes]
messages = db.get(keys)
```

This works just fine, as it's a list containment check as described above, and results in a single datastore query. The limitation you're thinking about is on the reverse: if you have a list, and you want to find a record that contains any item in that list, a subquery will be created for each element in the list.

Comment: Hi, does this mean that for a publish-subscribe relational network, I would have to "write" all the receivers' ids as a child of the message entity? I thought AppEngine is read-efficient not write-efficient, so wouldn't writing each subscriber's id with each message be inefficient? For e.g. a celebrity could have millions of subscribers, and this model would need to write each follower's ids with each message. Is this how I should model it?

Comment: To add to the above comment, how can I query to find all publishers or subscribers of a specific user? For e.g. if I have the following entity model: User: {id, data} Relation: {id, List of Publishers (ids), List of Subscribers (ids)} where Relation is a child of User. I understand that batch gets by id is optimized. However, can I include sort orders or filters to the batch gets? Thanks.

Comment: @AppEngineNoob The whole talk is about that tradeoff. I'd highly recommend watching the talk, and not just reading the slides.